# How can I add data created in a loop into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, function, for-loop

So, I'm working with this code to create a logistic map, and to create an histogram I want to add all the data of this function into an array (I'll call it owo bc why not), but when I add the `owo.append(f)`, if i print the array it comes empty. Inside the function there is a `print(f)` that show the numbers I want to add.

```
mu = [2.8, 3.3, 3.5, 3.8, 3.99]
N= 1000
x=0.1
owo=[]

def MeGustaElCereal(x, mu, N):
    f=x #Maybe start point?
    for n in range(N):
        f= mu*x*(1.0-x)
        x=f
        print(f)
        owo.append(f)
    return f

print(owo)
```

Also I know need to add more code to separate the results of every mu, maybe with another for?

Comment: You need to call to `MeGustaElCereal`.

Comment: Making the list global should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use special method **iadd** instead of append

```
owo.__iadd__([f])
```

**iadd**(y) . In other words, Python assigns the return value of your **iadd** implementation to the object you're "adding to", AFTER the implementation completes. This means it is possible to mutate the left side of the x += y operation so that the final implicit step fails.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the code in a function to run, you need to call it, with something like `MeGustaElCereal(x,mu,N)`.

However, even if you add this to your current code, you'll need to write `global owo` at the very top, because functions by default can't edit variables outside of the function.